# aws ec2 running python using crontab smtp error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, smtp

I am facing problem using aws ec2.

I am able to run my python script directly with :

```
[ec2-user@ip XXX.XXX.XX.XX ~]$ python3 get_data.py
```

But when I use crontab, the script return smtpconnect.error

```
CRON_TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong
0 9 * * * python3 /home/ec2-user/get_data.py >> home/ec2-user/out.log 2>$1
```

The log file :

> smtplib.SMTPConnectERROR: (421, b'4.4.5 Server busy, try again later.')

Why I can run it directly but got error when using crontab and how to solve it?

Comment: The server is busy. Try again later! Or it does not like you or the mail you are sending.

Comment: The python script will send email every 3 minutes and it worked, but in crontab there is an error.

Comment: permissions maybe? chmod 777 the files and try it